# Generate SSL on A record subdomain

Tags: ssl, digital-ocean

I have bought a domain on zeit and I've added A rules pointing to my Digital Ocean Droplet IP and I saw that https doesn't work.

How can I set up SSL on Droplet which is a subdomain of A record in zeit?

To sum up:

- I've bought a domain example.com
- I've added A record from blog.example.com to Droplet IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I would like to add SSL to the above configuration

I've tried `certbot --apache -d <domain>` but I've got an error about  "Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how old is certbot, ensure it's updated/latest

Comment: certbot 0.23.0

Followed by this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: that article is quite old, maybe use their docs instead of DO, https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-other